# function without a parameter c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters, tree

I want to understand how to write the `getheight` function without the parameter and it can still work.

my node.h file

```
Node();
~Node();

 int getHeight(Node* node);
//int getHeight(); without a parameter but those two can perform the same work

 int data;
 int height;
 Node* left;
 Node* right;
```

node.cpp:

```
   int node::height(Node *N){
   if (N == NULL)
     return 0;
   return N->height;
  }

//if I do not put the Node pointer into this function as a parameter, how should I write this function?
int node::height(){}
```

Comment: Use function overloading. Define one method with an argument, and another method without an argument. Also, you're calling it `getHeight` in the header file, but `height` in the code file.

Comment: `int getHeight() const { return height; }`. I'm entirely unclear what the purpose of your pointer parameter is in the first place, unless you're trying to write a free-function `getNodeHeight(const Node* n)`, and have it default to `0` on a NULL pointer.

Comment: I think you are new to c++ and try to do things C way. In c++, nonstatic class methods have a embedded 'this' pointer that points to the caller of the method. You can access, for example height, by `this->height`. If you are using methods or fields of this, you can omit `this` and just type `height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getHeight` is a member of `Node`, it has access to the `Node` object's members. You can just `return height;`. This is the same as doing `return this->height;`.

Of course, they don't perform the "same work". One returns the height of a `Node` passed by pointer as an argument, while the other returns the height of `this`. In fact, you don't seem to have a good reason for having the version that takes a pointer at all. It especially should not be a member function, because it doesn't depend on the state of `this`. If you really wanted a function with such a signature, I suggest making it a non-member function that uses the member `getHeight`:

```
int getHeight(Node *N) {
  if (N == NULL)
    return 0;
  return N->getHeight();
}
```

And if the only reason you are returning 0 when receiving a null pointer is to avoid runtime errors, I suggest making the function take a reference instead:

```
int getHeight(Node& N) {
  return N.getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ This may not be your issue, but too long for a comment.]

When trying to write:

```
int node::height(){}
```

You may have tried:

```
int node::height(){ return height;}
```

This of course gives a compile error. One means to return the value of the `height` member, but actually return the pointer to the member function itself.

You can write:

```
int node::height(){ return this->height;}
```

You can also by naming the method and data differently.

This is why `getHeight` and `setHeight` are often used. Some do prefer the convention that the member access method is `height`, so rename the member data to `int height_` or some such.

Answer (score 1):

I think conceptually you are misunderstanding something here.

From an OOP perspective, "what" are you trying to get the height of?

For your first function "Node *N" parameter is the object.

Now when you want to take out the parameter from the function call and declaration, it has to work with either an entirely arbitrary "height" that you give out, or you need to put getheight() as a member of the Node class in order to return the Node's height.